# Log4j custom rollover script to delete logs when filesystem usage reached certain percentage

Tags: javascript, log4j, log4j2, nashorn

I am using log4j for logging in my application. I want to delete the compressed files based on filesystem usage. So once filesystem is 80 percent full it should start deleting old compressed files. Log4j doesn't have any appender which can do that out of the box but it has ScriptCondition which can be used. In log4j documentation I only found groovy script (we dont have groovy installed on our systems). It also mentions that javascript, nashorn will also work. I wrote following script just to see if it runs or not.

```
<configuration status="trace" name="REST Servlet Logging Configuration">
        <Properties>
                <Property name="xx">xx</Property>
        </Properties>
        <appenders>
                <RollingFile name="xx"
                        fileName="xx"
                        filePattern="xx.log.%i.gz" append="true"
                        bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="false" fileOwner="xx"
                        fileGroup="xx" filePermissions="rw-r-----">
                        <Policies>
                                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="4 MB" />
                        </Policies>
                        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100" fileIndex="min">
                        <Delete basePath="${xx}" maxDepth="1">
                        <ScriptCondition>
                        <Script name="superstitious" language="javascript"><![CDATA[
                             var  exec  = require('child_process');
                                exec("df -h / | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                                        if(error) {
                                                 console.log('error: ${error.message}');
                                                 return;
                                         }
                                        if(stderr) {
                                                console.log('stderr: ${stderr}');
                                                return;
                                        }
                                         console.log('stdout: ${stdout}');
                                        statusLogger.trace("stdout in trace :${stdout}");
                                });
                            statusLogger.trace("running javascript");
                            result;
                        ]]>
                        </Script>
                    </ScriptCondition>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
```

In the logs I could see javascript is mentioned but in error I am getting nashorn exception.

```
05:58:46 UTC 2021 DEBUG createScript(name="superstitious", language="javascript", scriptText="var  exec  = require('child_process');
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z exec("df -h / | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z if(error) {
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z console.log('error: ${error.message}');
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z return;
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z }
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z if(stderr) {
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z console.log('stderr: ${stderr}');
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z return;
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z }
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z console.log('stdout: ${stdout}');
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z statusLogger.trace("stdout in trace :${stdout}");
2021-11-02T05:58:47.197Z });
```

But I am getting following exception

```
2021-11-02T06:00:41.581Z 2021-02-11 06:00:41,575 Log4j2-TF-1-RollingFileManager-1 ERROR Error running script superstitious javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:3:11 Expected : but found (
2021-11-02T06:00:41.581Z if(error) {
2021-11-02T06:00:41.582Z ^ in <eval> at line number 3 at column number 11
2021-11-02T06:00:41.582Z at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:482)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.582Z at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:549)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.582Z at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:536)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.582Z at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:414)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:167)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:244)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager$MainScriptRunner.execute(ScriptManager.java:239)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager$ThreadLocalScriptRunner.execute(ScriptManager.java:269)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager$1.run(ScriptManager.java:177)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:678)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager.execute(ScriptManager.java:174)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.ScriptCondition.selectFilesToDelete(ScriptCondition.java:81)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction.callScript(DeleteAction.java:98)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction.executeScript(DeleteAction.java:86)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction.execute(DeleteAction.java:82)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.CompositeAction.execute(CompositeAction.java:74)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$AsyncAction.execute(RollingFileManager.java:486)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.AbstractAction.run(AbstractAction.java:66)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:822)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException: <eval>:3:11 Expected : but found (
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z if(error) {
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z ^
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.error(AbstractParser.java:306)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.error(AbstractParser.java:291)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.expectDontAdvance(AbstractParser.java:362)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.expect(AbstractParser.java:349)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.propertyAssignment(Parser.java:2309)
2021-11-02T06:00:41.590Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.objectLiteral(Parser.java:2167)
```

I am not sure why its trying to compile it as nashorn script when I clearly mentioned javascript.
I am new to scripting so not sure what is going wrong here.

As per the suggestion by I changed the => to function and I am getting another exception

```
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z 2021-02-12 06:56:30,185 Log4j2-TF-1-RollingFileManager-2 ERROR Error running script superstitious javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "require" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:482)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:438)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.access$300(NashornScriptEngine.java:85)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$3.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:526)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:103)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager$MainScriptRunner.execute(ScriptManager.java:232)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager$ThreadLocalScriptRunner.execute(ScriptManager.java:269)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager$1.run(ScriptManager.java:177)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:678)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager.execute(ScriptManager.java:174)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.ScriptCondition.selectFilesToDelete(ScriptCondition.java:81)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction.callScript(DeleteAction.java:98)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction.executeScript(DeleteAction.java:86)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction.execute(DeleteAction.java:82)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.CompositeAction.execute(CompositeAction.java:74)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$AsyncAction.execute(RollingFileManager.java:486)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.AbstractAction.run(AbstractAction.java:66)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:822)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z Caused by: <eval>:1 ReferenceError: "require" is not defined
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:69)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:331)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:303)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.__noSuchProperty__(Global.java:1454)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at java.lang.invoke.DirectHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_L(DirectHandle.java:302)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at java.lang.invoke.AsTypeHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_X(AsTypeHandle.java:49)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at java.lang.invoke.BruteArgumentMoverHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_X(BruteArgumentMoverHandle.java:404)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$1$^eval_.:program(<eval>:1)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at java.lang.invoke.DirectHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_L(DirectHandle.java:302)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:649)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:506)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:405)
2021-12-02T06:56:30.192Z at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:433)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you're trying to use arrow functions, which are an ECMAScript 6 construct and Nashorn defaults to ECMAScript 5.1.

You can try to use `function (error, stdout, stderr) { … }` instead of `(error, stdout, stderr) => { … }`, I believe that will work.

#### TL;DR:

Nashorn does support a decent subset of ES6 but that needs to be enabled with a flag that's typically not supported by embeddings as you need to go outside the `javax.script` API and use Nashorn's own API,  `NashornScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(String...)` where you can pass it these flags, so it'd be

```java
ScriptEngine engine = NashornScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine("--language=es6");
...
```

FWIW, it'd make sense for us to provide an ES6-defaulting engine if you requested the language as "ecmascript-6" or similar. I'll think about this.

Comment: After I changed the => to functions, I am getting another exception which I updated in my original question

Comment: I don't think it's a particularly good idea to edit the original question, because then it confuses people who later stumble upon the page. As for your new problem, Nashorn is a pure ECMAScript implementation, it does not ship with a built-in implementation of CommonJS module system, someone would have to build that on top of it. To put it into perspective, Nashorn is similar to a plain V8 engine. It's e.g. Node.js that takes V8 and builds other functionality on top of it, e.g. "require". But neither Nashorn nor V8 have it built in.

Comment: Sure, I wont edit the question. I understand now that Nashorn does not support commonJS modules. My problem is why log4j is trying to run the script as Nashorn and JavaScript when in language I mentioned JavaScript.